# How can I the quasar timepicker after the user has picked a time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I'm not exactly thrilled with the way the timepicker behaves in quasar. And I'd hate to include another library just for that. The only thing I am no happy with is that it doesn't autoclose after picking a time. I worked out the date picker, but not the time picker. The closest I got to it was to check the v-model for a value. If it contains a value, I'm closing the picker. The problem is, I can't reopen the picker unless I erase the input field value.

Here's how I did it:

```
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
      <div class="q-gutter-sm row">
        <q-input filled v-model="time" mask="time" :rules="['time']">
          <template v-slot:append>
            <q-icon name="access_time" class="cursor-pointer">
              <q-popup-proxy 
                ref="qTimeProxy" 
                transition-show="scale" 
                transition-hide="scale">
                <q-time 
                   v-model="time" 
                   v-if="!time ? () => $refs.qTimeProxy.hide() : null">
                </q-time>
              </q-popup-proxy>
            </q-icon>
          </template>
        </q-input>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not ideal, as you can see. Any way I can make this better so I can reopen it even if it has a time already in it but also make it close when a time is picked out?

Here's the catch: This whole thing doesn't take into account the AM/PM. picking a time and ignoring the AM/PM is hardly efficient. Has anyone ever had to deal with this?

Here is the [**PLAYGROUND**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/ZEYOmEX?&editable=true&editors=101)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Just add @input event on `q-time` and call method to hide the `q-time` popover.

```
<q-input
                filled
                v-model="time"
                mask="time"
                :rules="['time']"
                >
                <template v-slot:append>
                  <q-icon name="access_time" class="cursor-pointer">
                    <q-popup-proxy
                      ref="qTimeProxy"
                    >
                      <q-time
                        v-model="time"
                        @input="closeDialog"
                      ></q-time>
                    </q-popup-proxy>
                  </q-icon>
                </template>
              </q-input>


  methods:  {
    closeDialog () {
      this.$refs.qTimeProxy.hide()
    }
  }
```

Working codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/yLyJwWq?editors=1010

Comment: What about having two or more time or date pickers?

Comment: you can assign different ref and then use it